# Como mostrais el contenido guardado con ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor

Después de guardar el contenido de ckeditor en la base de datos como lo mostrais para que interprete el contenido y no lo muestre tal cual como por ejemplo:

**hola** *comunidad*

he pensado en la función htmlspecialchars() pero también dejaría parte del contenido por interpretar o eso creo..

Comment: ahora mismo el código me queda asi en vez de interpretarlo.. < p >< strong >hola< / strong >  <em >comunidad</em >< / p >

<p >< em >< iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src =  "https://es.stackoverflow.com"><  /iframe >< / em>< / p >

Comment: Nadie se le ocurre nada ??

Answer (score 1):

Al imprimir la variable con el contenido debes estar dentro de:

```
  {!! $contenido !!}
```